# Кто может подробно объяснить клиент-сервер технологию?

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер, клиент, технологии

Я не понимаю некоторые вещи. Например, я хочу, чтобы мой сервер работал удаленно, как мне его поместить на хост?

- Как включить сервер на хосте?
- Как им и через что управлять?
- Клиенты могут подключаться с любого компа?
- Если хост с паролем тогда что?

Можете доступно объяснить?

Comment: Что такое хост?

Comment: ну хост для меня это место куда можно поместить сервер (место в дата-центре например) я просто не знаю этого ничего , но явно ,Чтобы мой сервер не был на моем компе и работал постоянно

Comment: Попробуйте для начала почитать [Transmission Control Protocol](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (сразу предупрежу, вероятно внутри придется не раз ходить по ссылкам и гуглить непонятные места)

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разберёмся немного с понятиями.

- **Хост** – это любой узел сети Интернет, как клиент, так и сервер, как смартфон, так и ПК. Каждый хост в рамках своей сети имеет IP адрес. Хосты обмениваются сообщениями между друг другом и внутри самих себя, и [все сообщения имеют порт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)), по которому определяется, какая программа будет обрабатывать это сообщение.
- **Сервер (1)** – целый компьютер (или часть его, виртуальная машина) где-то вдалеке, на котором висят программы, к которым обращаются другие программы (клиенты), чаще всего по запросам  юзеров. Владелец сервера волен ставить на нём любое ПО и ограничен лишь местом на диске, оперативкой и вычислительными мощностями.
- **Сервер (2)** – программа на сервере из определения 1, которая принимает, обрабатывает и отвечает на запросы программ-клиентов по сети Интернет. Эти программы могут возвращать и HTML страницы для браузеров, и бинарные данные

То есть, арендуя VPS / VDS или полноценный компьютер вы получаете физический сервер (1), с которым обычно взаимодействуют с помощью [командной строки SSH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH) для работы с большинством программ и с помощью [FTP для передачи данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP). Они всегда с паролем (иначе бы любой мог управлять сервером), но это совсем не сложно.

Процесс разработки таков: вы пишете код, отлаживаете его на своём компьютере, потом переносите по FTP на удалённый сервер, с помощью SSH устанавливаете и обновляете все зависимости (необходимые библиотеки и фреймворки), затем запускаете и настраиваете свои программы. В простонародье это называется *"поднять сервак"* (сервер из определения №2).

- **Хостинг** – это когда вы арендуете не полноценный компьютер или VPS и делаете там вообще что вздумается, а только ограниченный функционал. Часто это только HTML (может кто-то ещё помнит Ucoz) или только PHP или только сайты на Wordpress или только сайты на Python (например, [PythonAnyWhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)) и так далее, каких только хостингов не напридумывали. На хостинге часто если есть даже возможность кодить, то есть ограничения и в технологиях и во фреймворках. Однако для простых задач использовать хостинг бывает значительно удобнее, чем поднимать полноценный сервер – не нужно настраивать программное окружение, и часто они предоставляют удобную онлайн-панель вместо SSH.
- Стоит отметить, что также существуют **PAAS (сервисы-платформы)**, которые бывают очень близки к описанному определению хостинга. Они могут давать значительно больше возможностей, чем рядовой хостинг, но всё также имеют свои ограничения. Пример – [Google AppEngine](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine). Как и у хостингов, у большинства PAAS свои собственные средства загрузки кода, запуска/остановки программ и прочего.

---

Насчёт подключений: здесь всё снова зависит от (А) ваших технологий, а также (Б) условий клиентов и серверов.

- **А:** WiFi сети во многих публичных местах накладывают ограничения на TCP/UDP. В некоторых случаях бывают проблемы при отсутствии [SSL/HTTPS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). И много других нюансов, которые возникают только в специфических ситуациях.
- **Б:** фаерволы и правительственные блокировки могут помешать взаимодействию Ваших клиентов и серверов. Актуально в последнее время, но не мешает с выбором нормального провайдера хостинга/VPS.

---

В общем, полностью конкретные ответы на Ваши вопросы сложно дать, очень разные есть нюансы, и в каждом случае нужно разбираться индивидуально.

Для начала советую попробовать несколько разных хостингов (они бывают бесплатными в определенных лимитах), используйте просто HTTP запросы с любым содержимым – во многих случаях этого предостаточно. Затем, когда более-менее поймёте, как это всё работает, освоитесь в технологиях, можно уже будет более осознанно выбирать VPS (бесплатным не бывает), серверные технологии и любой нужный протокол взаимодействия с клиентами для своих задач.

Answer (score 2):

Клиент-сервер технология не имеет ничего общего с хостингом.

Сервер это программа, которая взаимодействует по определенному протоколу с другими программами, называемыми клиентом. Если речь идет о сети, то сервер это такой компьютер, который взаимодействует с другими компьютерами в сети, принимая запросы и выполняет какую-то функцию, которая осуществляется удаленно.

Хостинг - это выделение определенной части ресурсов сервера для удаленного использования. В зависимости от того-какие ресурсы выделяются очень меняется понятие хостинга. А также это понятие ничего общего не имеет с понятием хоста. Поскольку хост в сетевых терминах это узловой пункт, который имеет свой IP адрес.